# How to make application install for the user instead of the admin profile?

Tags: packages, sccm

I am trying to package an application but when I publish it to the software centre, it installs but not for the current user, it goes into the admin profile and isn't available for the user that downloads it.

This is the application I'm trying to package. 
http://www.hasil.gov.my/bt_goindex.php?bt_kump=2&bt_skum=4&bt_posi=1&bt_unit=7&bt_sequ=3

I have even tried to merely publish the software, without repackaging it, hence letting users choose the installation process, and it seems to go through the installation process, even shows the success page, but when I check the laptop, it's either in admin profile and won't appear for user or doesn't exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what type of package you are trying to create, but if you want to extract an msi without admin privileges, you can run the following command:

```
msiexec /a [path to msi file] /qb TARGETDIR=[path to target directory]
```

Note this might not modify any registry keys or perform any special commands that might be executed during the normal installation process, so this may only work with some applications.